# Determine which heroku app to push to

Tags: git, heroku, push

I checked out a project on github and now wish to deploy to heroku. When I enter 'heroku apps' it displays all the apps on my account. How can I tell which app I'll push to when I run

```
git push heroku master
```

Thanks,
  Gearoid.

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-app.git
git push heroku master
```

Comment: So is the 'heroku' after the 'add' action a variable that can be configured? ie. can I have heroku1, heroku2, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a heroku git remote - the General Info of the app on Heroku will list a git path

Set it up by, in your Git directory on your machine:

```
$ git remote add heroku (THAT URL)
```

then git push heroku master will know where to do

Answer (score 0):

You can view the url of `heroku` remote on the current repo by doing

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: When I run that I don't see any listing of a heroku remote. I originally had one but removed for safety's sake. Yet I can still run heroku rake db:migrate...